# In a jet cockpit: "console" or "instrument panel"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the correct term for the panel containing standard indicators such as the altimeter and airspeed indicator in a jet aircraft cockpit? Is it called **console** or **instrument panel**, or are both terms equivalent?

From reading on the subject, it looks like *console* refers to an individual set of instruments (one for pilot, another for co-pilot), but I don't know if this is correct.

**EDIT**

I'm looking for the term used by a civilian pilot of a private jet.

Comment: "Correct" is going to vary by context. A military speaker? Civilian pilot? A detective inspecting blood stains in a cockpit? The Boeing sales representative? An avionics technician doing maintenance? An aviation engineer? State your context. :)

Answer (score 8):

I am a US certificated private pilot, I would call it an "instrument panel" or just "panel". To differentiate pilot and co-pilot controls I would call it the "pilot's cluster" and "co-pilot's cluster", but "panel" could be interchanged with "cluster".

Comment: Do you fly jet aircraft as in the OP's question?

Answer (score 2):

On the various pilot blogs I read, "panel" is much more common than "console."

Keep in mind that many planes no longer have discrete instruments such as altimeters, they have multi-function displays that combine several instruments onto one display.  (FWIW, the Wikipedia article on [Glass Cockpits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_cockpit) uses "Instrument panel.")